# DataGridView text export to CSV

Tags: vb.net

I want to export all data from DataGridView to a CSV file, but the date format is wrong.
The date format I want is "dd-MMM-yy"

Full code:

```
Imports System.Data.OracleClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private da As OracleDataAdapter
    Private cb As OracleCommandBuilder
    Private ds As DataSet

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=testdb;User Id=teszt;Password=teszt;"
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand

        Dim sql As String = "select * from dont"
        cmd = New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
        cb = New OracleCommandBuilder(da)
        ds = New DataSet()

        da.Fill(ds)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        Dim xRowCount As Integer = 0
        Do Until xRowCount = DataGridView1.RowCount
            DataGridView1.Rows(xRowCount).Cells(2).Style.Format = Format("dd-MMM-yy")
            DataGridView1.Rows(xRowCount).Cells(1).Style.Format = Format("dd-MMM-yy")
            xRowCount = xRowCount + 1
        Loop
        conn.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim StrExport As String = ""

        For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            StrExport &= """" & C.HeaderText & ""","
        Next
        StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
        StrExport &= Environment.NewLine

        For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
                If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                    StrExport &= """" & C.Value.ToString & ""","
                Else
                    StrExport &= """" & "" & ""","
                End If
            Next
            StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
            StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
        Next

        Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\rg\teszt.csv")
        tw.Write(StrExport)
        tw.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm working from an Oracle SQL database

I tried this:

```
 Dim StrExport As String = ""
     For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        StrExport &= """" & C.HeaderText & ""","
    Next
    StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
    StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
    For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
            If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                StrExport &= """" & C.Value.ToString & ""","
            Else
                StrExport &= """" & "" & ""","
            End If
        Next
        StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
        StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
    Next
    Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\rg\teszt.csv")
    tw.Write(StrExport)
    tw.Close()
```

currently looks like this and that's not good:

"264117","2019.01.14. 0:00:00","2019.06.01. 0:00:00","sikeres eredmény","továbbra jogosult"
"264547","2019.01.15. 0:00:00","2019.06.02. 0:00:00","sikeres eredmény","továbbra nem jogosult"

I would like it to look like this in the csv file:

"264117","19-JAN.  -14","19-JUN.  -01","sikeres eredmény","továbbra jogosult"
"264547","19-JAN.  -15","19-JUN.  -02","sikeres eredmény","továbbra nem jogosult"

Comment: `.Style.Format` is the presentation format. The underlying Type is still DateTime. You need to reformat the DateTime field(s) with the pattern you need, when writing the values to a file.

Comment: So, `If C.ValueType = GetType(Date) Then 'Format the Value End If`.

Comment: Also, see the [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) Class. Bare-bones but useful when converting to/from a simple CSV file. Btw, do you really need to enclose the values in double quotes?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I couldn't paste it into my code, could you clarify what I should do? 

Yes it should look like that in the csv file :  "264547", "19-JAN. -15", "19-JUN. 02 "," sikeres eredmény "," rendelkezésre nem jogosult "

Because it is loaded elsewhere and only accepts this format.
Sorry for the bad English knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) class is used to read structured text files.
It allows to specify the Fields separator and other variant of the record format.  For example we can specify whether the Fields values are enclosed in quotes, using the [TextFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes) property.

It's just a parser, we cannot use it write to a file, only read from one.
But, of course, we can use it to validate a CSV formatted file, when needed.

This is a generic method that writes to a file the structure and values of a DataGridView's content.
The **`TextFieldParser`** class is then used to validate the output that this method generates.

You can pass some parameters to the **`CSVSaveDGVData`** method:

- The path of the file where the data will be stored. If the file does not exist, it will be created. A [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter) is use to write the data to a File. Note that I have set the Encoding to **`UTF8`**, even though it's the default: just to remind that a different Encoding could be specified, should it be needed.
- The DataGridView which is the source of the Data.
- A specific format to use when the Cell type is of Type `DateTime` (`Date`).
- A specific **`CultureInfo`**, if the decimal values need to be formatted using the a specific Culture format. If none is specified, it defaults to **`InvariantCulture`**.

Important note about `null`/`DBNull` handling: the current **`Cell.Value`** conversion, handles `null`/`DBNull` values as empty strings: the null format of a Field actually depends on what is reading these values back. You'll need to adapt it, if something else is required.

Sample call:

```
Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hu-HU")
If CSVSaveDGVData("test.csv", DataGridView1, "dd-MMM.-yy", culture) Then
    'All good
End If
```

---

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Function CSVSaveDGVData(filePath As String, control As DataGridView, dateTimeFormat As String, Optional culture As CultureInfo = Nothing) As Boolean
    Dim decimalFormat = If(culture, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim dateFormat = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTimeFormat), culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern, dateTimeFormat)

    Dim columns As String = String.Join(","c, control.Columns.OfType(Of DataGridViewColumn).Select(Function(c) ChrW(34) & c.Name & ChrW(34)))
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(filePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
        writer.WriteLine(columns)

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In control.Rows
            If row.IsNewRow Then Continue For
            Dim record As New List(Of String)
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim fieldType As Type = cell.ValueType
                Dim fieldValue As String
                Select Case fieldType
                    Case GetType(Single), GetType(Decimal), GetType(Double)
                        fieldValue = If(cell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value,
                            CType(cell.Value, Decimal).ToString(culture.NumberFormat),
                            String.Empty)
                    Case GetType(Date)
                        fieldValue = If(cell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value,
                            DirectCast(cell.Value, Date).ToString(dateFormat),
                            String.Empty)
                    Case GetType(Image)
                        fieldValue = cell.ValueType.ToString()
                    Case Else
                        fieldValue = cell.Value?.ToString()
                End Select
                record.Add(ChrW(34) & fieldValue & ChrW(34))
            Next
            writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", record))
            record.Clear()
        Next
    End Using
    Return CSVValidate(filePath)
End Function

Private Function ValidateCSV(filePath As String) As Boolean
    Using tfp As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath)
        tfp.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        tfp.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Try
            While Not tfp.EndOfData
                sb.Append(tfp.ReadFields)
            End While
        Catch exIO As IOException
            MessageBox.Show($"Invalid File: {exIO.Message}")
            Return False
        Catch exIDX As IndexOutOfRangeException
            MessageBox.Show($"Invalid Data format: {exIDX.Message}")
            Return False
        Catch exIO As FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MessageBox.Show($"Invalid Data format at line {exIO.Message}")
            Return False
        Finally
            sb.Clear()
        End Try
    End Using
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use  tostring("yy-MMM.-dd") for  every C.ValueType that is a date.